# Using Powershell to change filenames

Tags: powershell, file-rename, delay-bind

When did changing filenames become so complicated??
All I want to do is add '_a' to a directory of files (with no extension)

The following does not work:

```
Rename-Item -newname { $_BaseName + '_a' } -whatif

Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no
input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At line:1 char:22
+ Rename-Item -newname { $_BaseName + '_a' } -whatif
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

then:

```
Rename-Item -Path C:\users\r-waibel\Downloads\Mar723_pod3-m $_.basename -Newname ($_.basename + "_a") -whatif

Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At line:1 char:1
+ rename-item -Path C:\users\r-waibel\Downloads\Mar723_pod3-m $_.basena ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: An example: `Get-Item -Path .\DataFiles | ForEach-Object {$_ | Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName ($_.BaseName + '_a')}` returns _`What if: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: D:\PShell\DataFiles Destination: D:\PShell\DataFiles_a".`_ See [`$_` contains the current object in the pipeline object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add some background information to [Mathias R. Jessen's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75941791/45375):

- The [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) only ever has a meaningful value inside [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), and most commonly refers to the current input object received *via the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines)*.
- The script block passed to `-NewName` in your
  `Rename-Item -NewName { $_BaseName + '_a' } -WhatIf` command is a so-called [*delay-bind script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), which therefore indeed requires *pipeline input*:

  - Note that delay-bind script blocks only work with parameters that are explicitly designed to bind to pipeline input (and that they mustn't be of type `[script block]` or `[object]`).
  - In effect, instead of providing a *static value* to `-NewName` you're passing *a piece of code* that gets evaluated *for each pipeline input object* and therefore allows the calculation of dynamic, per-input-object values.
  - If there is *no* pipeline input, the command cannot function, and you'll get the error that includes `Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input.`
- By contrast, `-NewName ($_.basename + "_a")` passes an (ultimately) *static* value to `-NewName`; that is, the expression is evaluated *once, up front*, and its result is passed as a static value to the parameter.

  - For the reasons explained above, `$_` has no meaningful value in this context; it is `$null`, so `$_.basename` is `$null` too, and the overall result is just `_a`.
  - However, because you also tried to use `$_.basename` as an *additional, positional argument*
    (`rename-item -Path C:\users\r-waibel\Downloads\Mar723_pod3-m $_.basename -Newname ($_.basename + "_a") -whatif`), the [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) call broke fundamentally, due to that argument (whose value happens to be `$null`) not being recognized.
  - This is what the error message `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.` indicates.
  - To solve your task *without* a delay-bind script block (the latter being preferable), but without having to hard-code the input file name, you'd need an aux. custom variable; e.g.:

    ```bash
     $file = Get-Item -LiteralPath C:\users\r-waibel\Downloads\Mar723_pod3-m
     $file | Rename-Item -NewName ($file.BaseName + '_a') -WhatIf
    ```

    - The above is the - more cumbersome, single-file-only - equivalent to using a delay-bind script block as follows:

      ```bash
       Get-Item -LiteralPath C:\users\r-waibel\Downloads\Mar723_pod3-m | 
         Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + '_a' } -WhatIf
      ```

---

As for:

> All I want to do is add '_a' to a directory of files (with no extension)

Using the flexibility of delay-bind script blocks discussed above, this is then as simple as piping the output from a [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call that outputs *all* files to rename to your `Rename-Item` call:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath C:\users\r-waibel\Downloads\ | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + '_a' } -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 2):

As the first error message states, you need to provide some sort of *input* for `-NewName {...}` to work.

Pipe the corresponding file items to `Rename-Item` and it'll work:

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\directory -File |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + "_a" } -WhatIf
```